# Correct semantic html5 tag for single top level nav and sub links

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup

I have the following structure for navigation:

```
Models
    Model 1
    Model 2
    Model 3
    Model 4
```

I would like to use the nav tag since this is the main navigation on the site

I cant also decide about what tag "Models" should be in.  Is it a title within a nav tag - im not sure thats correct?

I therefore have the following so far but am unhappy with it - particularly the title part:

```
<nav>
    <h1>Models</h1>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#">Model 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 2</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 3</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 4</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 5</a>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

If Models itself is part of the navigation you should nest `<ul>` list within it.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Models
            <ul>
                <li><a href="”#”">Model 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Model 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Model 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Model 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Model 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Products
            <ul>
                <li><a href="”#”">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Product 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Product 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Product 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="”#”">Product 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is the correct markup! Since "models" is the title of the list, this is the correct placement of the `<h1>` element. The only thing I would change is `<ol>` to `<ul>`.
You can read more about menu's in this article at the bottom. http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html

```
<nav>
    <h1>Models</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Model 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 2</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 3</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 4</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 5</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Talking about semantics, your `h1` as a main title should be outside of your nav, or change it by a `h2` or `p`, because main title it is not part of navigation.

about navigation, it should be something like this:

```
<header>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <nav>
        <h2>Models</h2>
        <ul role="navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Model 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Model 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Model 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Model 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Model 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Don't forget aria roles to indicate browsers what things are.
Hope you find it useful.

Comment: `navigation` role is not allowed on the `ul` element. For ul, role must be one of `directory`, `list`, `listbox`, `menu`, `menubar`, `tablist`, `toolbar`, `tree` or `presentation` See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#aria-role-attribute

Comment: It’s perfectly fine to have `h1` in `nav`, as `nav` is a sectioning element. It doesn’t matter semantically if you use `h1` or `h2` there.

Answer (score 0):

`nav` is a [sectioning element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#sectioning-content-0). If you don’t provide a heading for a sectioning element, the [outline algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#outlines) creates an implicit/undefined heading.

So if "Models" correctly describes these navigation links (and it seems that this is the case), it’s good to use it as heading. You can use `h1` or the corresponding heading level `h2`-`h6` (depending on where your `nav` is placed in the outline).

Using a list for the links itself is good, too. However, typically you’d want to use a `ul` instead of a `ol` here. Only use `ol` if the order of the links is meaningful and visitors should visit the pages in that (and no other) order. If they are simply sorted alphabetically, that doesn’t qualify for `ol`.

So I’d go with:

```
<nav>
    <h1>Models</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Model 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 2</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 3</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 4</a>
        <li><a href="#">Model 5</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```